# Pause the processing of saving the data when modal popup show

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, modalpopupextender

How can I pause the processing of saving the data when modal popup showed?
and when I click the button inside that modal popup, the execution of saving the data will continue to process.

my Modal popup is acting like a message box...

**here is my sample code:**

```
bool overlap= false;
foreach (ListItem item in chkMBoxEmployeeList.Items)
{
    if (overlap == true)
    {
      //Saving of data 
    }
    else if (overlap == false)
    {
       ModalpopupExtender2.Show();
       //In this condition, I will pause the execution of saving the data
    }
}
```

---

```
//I used this after the ModalpopupExtender2.Show():
return;

//but I think, this will not be the answer, because my code will become very long if use that.  I will rewrite again my code in the button in modalpopup if I use that.
```

Should I use **Threading**? is **Threading** working on ASP.Net?

Comment: This might point you in the right direction: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Comment: @pm_2 - I know how to use modalpopup, the problem is when modalpopup was start to show, the process will still continue to process.

Answer (score 0):

Your save process is happening on the **server** but the modal dialog would be displayed on the **client**. You can't make the server wait for the user in the browser to respond. Instead the server processing has to end and send the modified page to the browser. Now the browser will again submit all the data together with the confirmation. Since you are using ASP.NET WebForms you get lucky since it handles the state automatically for such scenarios.

```
public void Save(bool confirmed)
{
    if (!confirmed && NeedsConfirmation())
    {
        ShowModalWindow();
        return;
    }

    // here perform the operation.
}

public void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is the button that is normally displayed on the form
    this.Save(false);
}

public void ButtonConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this button is located within the modal dialog - so it is not shown before that.
    this.Save(true);
}
```